# How to build a Spark (Scala) function to search documents for terms

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I would like to search an array of documents for terms, then count the number of occurrences.  Here is a working example that counts the term "one".

```
val temp_rdd = sc.parallelize(Array("one item", "two item", "one two three"))
val df = temp_rdd.toDF("line")
val get_ones = df.filter(col("line").like("%one%"))
get_ones.count()

// res43: Long = 2
```

Now, I'd like to turn this into a function that accepts the term as an argument, but I can't get it to work.  Here's my best attempt.

```
def countTerm(df: RDD[String], str:String): Int = {
  val terms = df.filter(col("line").like(str))
  return terms.count() 
}
countTerm(df, "%one%")
```

I get this error, which I can't figure out.

```
<console>:56: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.Column
 required: String => Boolean
         val terms = df.filter(col("line").like(str))
                                               ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up DataFrames method with RDD :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

def countTerm(df: DataFrame, str:String): Long = {
  val terms = df.filter($"line".like(str))
  terms.count
}

val rdd = sc.parallelize(Array("one item", "two item", "one two three"))
val df = rdd.toDF("line")

df.filter($"line".like("%one%")).show
// +-------------+
// |         line|
// +-------------+
// |     one item|
// |one two three|
// +-------------+

countTerm(df,"%one%")
// res3: Long = 2
```